# How to create web page with left pane and draggable objects in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm basically a newbie to Javascript/jQuery. I have been tasked with creating a web page that should have elements to the left of the page in sitting a "pane". These items can then be dragged outside of this pane and into
a "droppable" div area to the right. The whole area to the right will be a droppable zone.

I am not sure of where to start (with pure Javascript or use a library?).

Any help in the right direction would be great.

I am basically using Polymer web components and from what I am googling a lot of answers are pointing to JQuery UI. A point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For drag and drop option you can use [Draggable JS](https://shopify.github.io/draggable/) maintained by shopify.

1. [Draggable documentation](https://github.com/Shopify/draggable/tree/master/src/Draggable)
2. [Droppable documentation](https://github.com/Shopify/draggable/tree/master/src/Droppable)